# Passing array arguments to my own 2D function applied on Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am given the following pandas dataframe

```
df
                         long       lat  weekday  hour
dttm                                                  
2015-07-03 00:00:38  1.114318  0.709553        6     0
2015-08-04 00:19:18  0.797157  0.086720        3     0
2015-08-04 00:19:46  0.797157  0.086720        3     0
2015-08-04 13:24:02  0.786688  0.059632        3    13
2015-08-04 13:24:34  0.786688  0.059632        3    13
2015-08-04 18:46:36  0.859795  0.330385        3    18
2015-08-04 18:47:02  0.859795  0.330385        3    18
2015-08-04 19:46:41  0.755008  0.041488        3    19
2015-08-04 19:47:45  0.755008  0.041488        3    19
```

I also have a function that receives as input 2 arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def time_hist(weekday, hour):
    hist_2d=np.histogram2d(weekday,hour, bins = [xrange(0,8), xrange(0,25)])
    return hist_2d[0].astype(int)
```

I wish to apply my 2D function to each and every group of the following groupby:

```
df.groupby(['long', 'lat'])
```

I tried passing *args to .apply():

```
df.groupby(['long', 'lat']).apply(time_hist, [df.weekday, df.hour])
```

but I get an error: "The dimension of bins must be equal to the dimension of the  sample x."

Of course the dimensions mismatch. The whole idea is that I don't know in advance which mini [weekday, hour] arrays to send to each and every group.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)


def time_hist(x):
    hour = x.hour
    weekday = x.weekday
    hist_2d = np.histogram2d(weekday, hour, bins=[xrange(0, 8), xrange(0, 25)])
    return hist_2d[0].astype(int)


print(df.groupby(['long', 'lat']).apply(time_hist))
```

Output:

```
long      lat     
0.755008  0.041488    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
0.786688  0.059632    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
0.797157  0.086720    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
0.859795  0.330385    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
1.114318  0.709553    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
dtype: object
```